# How to verify whether new tab opened or not in selenium webdriver in Ruby?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a situation where I have to check whether after clicking on a link a new tab is opened or not. If the tab opens I want to check the title as well.

Does anyone have any idea about this in `Ruby` specifically please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct command to check it, but you can definitely do it with a combination of steps. When you click on a link, make sure to open it in a new tab. Use the below code to understand this:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
String exec = "window.open(link,'_blank');";  // replace link with your desired link
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(exec);
```

This will open the link in new tab successfully.

Now to verify whether the new tab is opened or not, you can switch to the new tab. If no error is raised, it means the new tab is opened just fine, else not.

```
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); //switches to new tab
```